How to load an external URL in <iframe> in Electron desktop app？
In the Electron desktop application, I want to embed an external link using, for example:“ http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html , always unsuccessful. The DevTools console displays an error:

I also searched on Google and asked ChatGPT, and got a similar answer. The solution is shown  below, but the problem still persists.
function createWindow(): void {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 670,
    show: false,
    frame: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    fullscreen:true,
    transparent: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false,
      contextIsolation:true,
      nodeIntegration: true, 
      webSecurity: true ,
      webviewTag: true,
    }
  });
  
  mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived(
    { urls: [ "*://*/*" ] }, 
    (details, callback) => {
      let responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders || {};
      if (responseHeaders['Content-Security-Policy']) {
        delete responseHeaders['Content-Security-Policy'];
      } else if (responseHeaders['content-security-policy']) {
        delete responseHeaders['content-security-policy'];
      }
      if(responseHeaders['x-frame-options']) {
        delete responseHeaders['x-frame-options'];
      }
      callback({cancel: false, responseHeaders: responseHeaders});
  });

